# iOS PHImageManager cancelImageRequest not working?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I'm using Photos Framework to populate a UICollectionView. It should be an easy pattern but I'm having problems canceling requests for hidden cells.

This is my code, taken from several examples:

```
#pragma mark - UICollectionView DataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_photos count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    GalleryViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@">>>>>>SHOWING CELL %d WITH MEMADDRESS %p", indexPath.row, cell);
    PHAsset *asset = [_photos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    PHImageRequestOptions *option = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
    option.synchronous = NO;
    option.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;
    option.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
    option.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeOpportunistic;
    option.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;

    PHImageRequestID requestId = cell.tag;
    if(requestId != 0)
    {
        [_imgManager cancelImageRequest:requestId];
        NSLog(@">>>>>>1ST CANCEL CELL %d WITH MEMADDRESS %p AND REQUESTID %d", indexPath.row, cell, requestId);
    }
    [cell.photoIV setImage:nil];
    cell.tag = [_imgManager requestImageForAsset:asset
                                      targetSize:CGSizeMake(CAMERA_GALLERY_SIZE, CAMERA_GALLERY_SIZE)
                //                          contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit
                                     contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault
                                         options:option
                                   resultHandler:^(UIImage *result, NSDictionary *info) {
                                       //if([self isRowVisible:indexPath])
                                       //{
                                         [cell.photoIV setImage:result];
                                         NSLog(@">>>>>>Assigning photo to cell %d with memaddress %p", indexPath.row, cell);
                                       //}
                                       //else
                                       //{
                                       //    NSLog(@">>>>>>We should assign photo to cell %d with memaddress %p but this cell is not visible", indexPath.row, cell);
                                       //}
                                   }];
    NSLog(@">>>>>>LOADING CELL %d WITH MEMADDRESS %p AND REQUESTID %d", indexPath.row, cell, requestId);
    if([_selectedPhotos containsObject:asset])
        [cell.selectedIV setHidden:NO];
    else
        [cell.selectedIV setHidden:YES];
    [cell.isMineIV setHidden:YES];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@">>>>>>HIDDING CELL %d WITH MEMADDRESS %p", indexPath.row, cell);
    [((GalleryViewCell *)cell).photoIV setImage:nil];
    PHImageRequestID requestId = cell.tag;
    if(requestId != 0)
    {
        [_imgManager cancelImageRequest:requestId];
        NSLog(@">>>>>>2ND CANCEL CELL %d WITH MEMADDRESS %p AND REQUESTID %d", indexPath.row, cell, requestId);
    }
}

-(BOOL) isRowVisible:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    NSArray *indexes = [_photosCV indexPathsForVisibleItems];
    for (NSIndexPath *index in indexes)
    {
        if (index.row == indexPath.row)
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Well, if I make a fast scroll down and up in the collection view each cell is refreshed several times, showing 2 or even 3 images in 1 or 2 seconds.
I'm trying to cancel previous request in the same cell when the cell is no longer visible or when the cell is visible again but looking at the results and looking at the logs it seems that no requests are being canceled.

These are my logs after I made a scroll down and a scroll up to the top of my list.

```
2016-10-24 22:10:46.284 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>HIDDING CELL 17 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x17351660
2016-10-24 22:10:46.286 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>2ND CANCEL CELL 17 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x17351660 AND REQUESTID 351
2016-10-24 22:10:46.288 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>HIDDING CELL 15 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1736a890
2016-10-24 22:10:46.289 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>2ND CANCEL CELL 15 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1736a890 AND REQUESTID 349
2016-10-24 22:10:46.291 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>SHOWING CELL 0 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1736a890
2016-10-24 22:10:46.291 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>1ST CANCEL CELL 0 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1736a890 AND REQUESTID 349
2016-10-24 22:10:46.293 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 0 with memaddress 0x1736a890
2016-10-24 22:10:46.293 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>LOADING CELL 0 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1736a890 AND REQUESTID 349
2016-10-24 22:10:46.298 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>SHOWING CELL 1 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x17351660
2016-10-24 22:10:46.298 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>1ST CANCEL CELL 1 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x17351660 AND REQUESTID 351
2016-10-24 22:10:46.301 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 1 with memaddress 0x17351660
2016-10-24 22:10:46.303 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>LOADING CELL 1 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x17351660 AND REQUESTID 351
2016-10-24 22:10:46.310 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>SHOWING CELL 2 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1744d350
2016-10-24 22:10:46.311 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>1ST CANCEL CELL 2 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1744d350 AND REQUESTID 350
2016-10-24 22:10:46.312 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 2 with memaddress 0x1744d350
2016-10-24 22:10:46.312 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>LOADING CELL 2 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1744d350 AND REQUESTID 350
2016-10-24 22:10:46.316 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>SHOWING CELL 3 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x171c0fd0
2016-10-24 22:10:46.317 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>1ST CANCEL CELL 3 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x171c0fd0 AND REQUESTID 348
2016-10-24 22:10:46.318 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 3 with memaddress 0x171c0fd0
2016-10-24 22:10:46.318 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>LOADING CELL 3 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x171c0fd0 AND REQUESTID 348
2016-10-24 22:10:46.325 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>SHOWING CELL 4 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x15f15b60
2016-10-24 22:10:46.339 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>1ST CANCEL CELL 4 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x15f15b60 AND REQUESTID 347
2016-10-24 22:10:46.363 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 4 with memaddress 0x15f15b60
2016-10-24 22:10:46.365 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>LOADING CELL 4 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x15f15b60 AND REQUESTID 347
2016-10-24 22:10:46.371 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>SHOWING CELL 5 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1710b1b0
2016-10-24 22:10:46.373 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>1ST CANCEL CELL 5 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1710b1b0 AND REQUESTID 346
2016-10-24 22:10:46.376 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 5 with memaddress 0x1710b1b0
2016-10-24 22:10:46.377 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>LOADING CELL 5 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x1710b1b0 AND REQUESTID 346
2016-10-24 22:10:46.399 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 23 with memaddress 0x171d3600
2016-10-24 22:10:46.401 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 16 with memaddress 0x1744d350
2016-10-24 22:10:46.408 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>HIDDING CELL 12 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x15feda90
2016-10-24 22:10:46.408 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>2ND CANCEL CELL 12 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x15feda90 AND REQUESTID 352
2016-10-24 22:10:46.409 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>HIDDING CELL 13 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x171d7d00
2016-10-24 22:10:46.409 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>2ND CANCEL CELL 13 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x171d7d00 AND REQUESTID 353
2016-10-24 22:10:46.410 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>HIDDING CELL 14 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x171ef8d0
2016-10-24 22:10:46.410 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>2ND CANCEL CELL 14 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x171ef8d0 AND REQUESTID 354
2016-10-24 22:10:46.430 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 19 with memaddress 0x15f15b60
2016-10-24 22:10:46.490 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 15 with memaddress 0x1736a890
2016-10-24 22:10:46.504 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 0 with memaddress 0x1736a890
2016-10-24 22:10:46.551 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 17 with memaddress 0x17351660
2016-10-24 22:10:46.614 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 13 with memaddress 0x171d7d00
2016-10-24 22:10:46.677 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 9 with memaddress 0x1735b730
2016-10-24 22:10:46.743 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 12 with memaddress 0x15feda90
2016-10-24 22:10:46.808 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 10 with memaddress 0x171e3660
2016-10-24 22:10:46.865 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 14 with memaddress 0x171ef8d0
2016-10-24 22:10:46.927 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 11 with memaddress 0x15f27020
2016-10-24 22:10:46.996 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 6 with memaddress 0x171d3600
2016-10-24 22:10:47.053 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 7 with memaddress 0x17133010
2016-10-24 22:10:47.088 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 3 with memaddress 0x171c0fd0
2016-10-24 22:10:47.114 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 4 with memaddress 0x15f15b60
2016-10-24 22:10:47.118 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 2 with memaddress 0x1744d350
2016-10-24 22:10:47.122 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 1 with memaddress 0x17351660
2016-10-24 22:10:47.125 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 8 with memaddress 0x15f06e30
2016-10-24 22:10:47.213 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 5 with memaddress 0x1710b1b0
```

As you can see, cell 17 (0x17351660) is hidden and I cancel its request.

```
2016-10-24 22:10:46.284 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>HIDDING CELL 17 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x17351660
2016-10-24 22:10:46.286 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>2ND CANCEL CELL 17 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x17351660 AND REQUESTID 351
```

Just after that, cell 1 (0x17351660) is shown and I init a new request for this cell.

```
2016-10-24 22:10:46.298 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>SHOWING CELL 1 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x17351660
2016-10-24 22:10:46.298 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>1ST CANCEL CELL 1 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x17351660 AND REQUESTID 351
2016-10-24 22:10:46.301 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 1 with memaddress 0x17351660
2016-10-24 22:10:46.303 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>LOADING CELL 1 WITH MEMADDRESS 0x17351660 AND REQUESTID 351
```

But after some time I have this:

```
2016-10-24 22:10:46.551 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 17 with memaddress 0x17351660
2016-10-24 22:10:47.122 Fotoloop[9834:4281410] >>>>>>Assigning photo to cell 1 with memaddress 0x17351660
```

And I can seen 2 images shown in that cell in a second.
If I uncomment the isRowVisible block I don't see this ugly effect but I keep thinking that there is a problem canceling requests with my code that can leads to poor performances with a large number of photos.
What am I missing here?

Comment: I would like to add a comment just in case someone has the same problem as me. If you are working with iOS 10, my method isRowVisible will return false very often because with iOS 10 by default cellForItemAtIndexPath is called before the cell is shown. I had to put [mycollectionview setPrefetchingEnabled:NO] to avoid this.

Comment: I still have the same behaviour you described: is there a bug filed to Apple? Or are we doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I am implementing Photos into a UICollectionView and discovered the same results as you.  At first, I thought cancelImageRequest wasn't working because when scrolling fast, the performance suffered, and I would see 2-3 images flicker through a cell until finally landing on the correct image.  I also noticed that the PHImageCancelledKey will never exist in the resultHandler info dictionary even though I am cancelling on collectionView didEndDisplaying.

However, I did solve my issues which I will explain now.  Because PHImageManager requestImage is asynchronous, this is most likely running on a background queue which can cause strange results when doing anything UI related. In the resultHandler, make sure to handle everything on the main queue and it should solve the issues you see.  At least it did for me.

I am testing on an iPhone 5s scrolling through 800 images.

Here is a sample of my collectionView code with my current tests.

I also provided below where I load my photo fetch results and cache them.  The self.imageManager I use is a PHCachingImageManager.

Just want to add that you'll notice I have boolean checks for wasCancelled and isSameRequest.  Those are irrelevant because the cancelled key never exists and now that everything is handled on the main queue the flickering through images no longer occurs.  I left those there incase you wanted to see for yourself.

```
// MARK: UICollectionViewDelegate

public func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if let assetFetchResult = self.assetFetchResult
    {
        return assetFetchResult.count
    }

    return 0
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell: PhotoLibraryCell = self.itemsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: PhotoLibraryCell.ReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoLibraryCell

    cell.backgroundColor = .white
    cell.drawBorder(color: .lightGray, borderWidth: 1)
    cell.imageView.image = nil

    if let assetFetchResult = self.assetFetchResult
    {
        let asset: PHAsset = assetFetchResult.object(at: indexPath.row)
        let itemSize: CGSize = Settings.ItemSize
        let targetSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: itemSize.width * 2, height: itemSize.height * 2)

        if (asset.mediaType == .image)
        {
            cell.imageRequestID = self.imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil, resultHandler: { (image: UIImage?, info: [AnyHashable: Any]?) in

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    var isDegraded: Bool = false
                    var wasCancelled: Bool = false
                    var isSameRequest: Bool = false

                    if let degraded = (info?[PHImageResultIsDegradedKey] as? NSNumber)?.boolValue
                    {
                        isDegraded = degraded
                    }

                    if let cancelled = (info?[PHImageCancelledKey] as? NSNumber)?.boolValue
                    {
                        wasCancelled = cancelled
                    }

                    if let id = info?[PHImageResultRequestIDKey] as? NSNumber, let cellRequestID = cell.imageRequestID
                    {
                        let requestID: Int = id.intValue

                        isSameRequest = Int(cellRequestID) == requestID
                    }

                    if (!isDegraded && !wasCancelled && isSameRequest)
                    {
                        cell.imageView.image = image
                    }
                }
            })                
        }
        else if (asset.mediaType == .video)
        {

        }
    }

    return cell
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    if let photoLibraryCell = cell as? PhotoLibraryCell
    {
        if let imageRequestID = photoLibraryCell.imageRequestID
        {
            self.imageManager.cancelImageRequest(imageRequestID)
        }
    }
}

public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    return Settings.ItemSize
}

// MARK: Assets

public func reloadAssets()
{
    let photoResult: PHFetchResult<PHAsset> = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: nil)

    self.assetFetchResult = photoResult

    self.itemsCollectionView.reloadData()

    //enumerate assets and start caching them
    let backgroundQueue: DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "enumerate-phassets-background-queue", qos: .background, target: nil)
    backgroundQueue.async {

        var assets: [PHAsset] = Array()
        let itemSize: CGSize = Settings.ItemSize
        let targetSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: itemSize.width * 2, height: itemSize.height * 2)

        photoResult.enumerateObjects({ (asset: PHAsset, index: Int, stopEnumeration: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
            assets.append(asset)

            let reachedEnd: Bool = index == photoResult.count - 1
            if (reachedEnd)
            {
                self.imageManager.startCachingImages(for: assets, targetSize: targetSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: nil)
            }
        })
    }
}
```